# Compare two database table and show changed column names

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, tmp1 and tmp2:

tmp1:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | mum  | rajpur  | rajpur1 |
| 3  | mum1 | rajpur1 | rajpur2 |
| 4  | mum3 | rajpur3 | rajpur4 |
| 5  | mum4 | rajpur4 | rajpur5 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

tmp2:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | mum  | rajpur  | rajpur1 |
| 3  | mum1 | rajpur6 | rajpur7 |
| 4  | mum3 | rajpur3 | rajpur8 |
| 5  | mum4 | rajpur4 | rajpur5 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

Here I have applied one sql query though which, the null valued attribute's id or unmatched valued attribute's id will be retrieved from first table with compare to the second table:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM   tmp1 a
       INNER JOIN tmp2 b
               ON a.id = b.id
                  AND ( ( a.name IS NULL
                           OR a.add1 IS NULL
                           OR a.add2 IS NULL )
                         OR ( a.name != b.name
                               OR a.add1 != b.add1
                               OR a.add2 != b.add2 ) );
```

The above sql query gives me the below result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
+----+
```

This is perfectly fine and I have got my desired result using the above query.

Now I want to retrieve those column's name where the changes appeared in first table with compare to the second table, or null values holding column name in first table, and I want my result looks like below:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | Changed Columns |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | name,add1,add2  |
| 3  | add1,add2       |
| 4  | add2            |
+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: "When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Concat_ws()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function with conditional checks using [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). Good thing about `Concat_Ws` function is that if there is `NULL` value in the parameter list, it ignore it (instead of concatenating it).

So, we can use the `CASE .. WHEN` statements to check for the columns individually, and if they match our conditions, then return the column name (as string), else return `null`.

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  CONCAT_WS(',', 
            CASE WHEN a.name IS NULL OR a.name <> b.name THEN 'name' ELSE NULL END,
            CASE WHEN a.add1 IS NULL OR a.add1 <> b.add1 THEN 'add1' ELSE NULL END, 
            CASE WHEN a.add2 IS NULL OR a.add2 <> b.add2 THEN 'add2' ELSE NULL END
           ) AS Changed_Columns
FROM   tmp1 a
       INNER JOIN tmp2 b
               ON a.id = b.id
                  AND ( ( a.name IS NULL
                           OR a.add1 IS NULL
                           OR a.add2 IS NULL )
                         OR ( a.name <> b.name
                               OR a.add1 <> b.add1
                               OR a.add2 <> b.add2 ) );
```

**Result**

```
| id  | Changed_Columns |
| --- | --------------- |
| 1   | name,add1,add2  |
| 3   | add1,add2       |
| 4   | add2            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qiUUnbQF9WtppEESjeHiXd/1)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the column names if they are not equal like this:

```
select a.id,
  trim(trailing ',' from concat(
    case when a.name = b.name then '' else 'name,' end,
    case when a.add1 = b.add1 then '' else 'add1,' end,
    case when a.add2 = b.add2 then '' else 'add2' end
  )) `Changed Columns`
from tmp1 a inner join tmp2 b 
on a.id=b.id and (
  (a.name is NULL or a.add1 is NULL or a.add2 is NULL) 
  or 
  (a.name!=b.name or a.add1!=b.add1 or a.add2!=b.add2)
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ba1ayrC7Esj5Tq5SipsveE/1).
Results:

```
| id  | Changed Columns |
| --- | --------------- |
| 1   | name,add1,add2  |
| 3   | add1,add2       |
| 4   | add2            |
```

Comment: seems like the ON clause would miss a change report when a column is changed from a non-NULL value to NULL  e.g. consider `a.name = 'foo'  AND b.name IS NULL`  the last line of the ON clause could be changed to `or NOT (a.name <=> b.name AND a.add1 <=> b.add1 AND a.add2 <=> b.add2 )`

Comment: @spencer7593 What WHERE clause?

Comment: The conditions in the ON clause is the OP's working code. I did not change it.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the "working code" does not work for some conditions; really depends in the interpretation of the spec. Absent a more precise requirement, I would think a change from a non-NULL value to a NULL value would be considered a change.

Comment: You should point that to the OP although I think that the case you mention is covered here: `a.name is NULL or a.add1 is NULL or a.add2 is NULL`

Comment: The case I suggested is *not* covered in that condition. Consider `a.name = 'foo' and b.name IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
select id, group_concat(f order by f) as `Changed Columns` from (
    select tmp1.id, 'name' as f from tmp1 join tmp2 on tmp1.id = tmp2.id and (tmp1.name is null or tmp1.name <> tmp2.name)
    union
    select tmp1.id, 'add1' as f from tmp1 join tmp2 on tmp1.id = tmp2.id and (tmp1.add1 is null or tmp1.add1 <> tmp2.add1)
    union
    select tmp1.id, 'add2' as f from tmp1 join tmp2 on tmp1.id = tmp2.id and (tmp1.add2 is null or tmp1.add2 <> tmp2.add2)
) sq
group by id
order by id
;
```

[See DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qiUUnbQF9WtppEESjeHiXd/6)